# php select and display info from sql ordered by minutes, hours, days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, events, calendar

I have a quick question for some one who can tell me how to make my script
I have this table

```
id  name            day     hour    min
1   Test event1     *       *       30
2   Test event2     *       *       40
3   Test event3     *       14      15
4   Test event4     15      18      10
5   Test event5     21      *       8
```

The * means will run at all time on that minutes. Ex event5 will run only on day 21 any hour at minute 8.

What I want is to display on my page is the next event 'name' and 'time' ex:

```
    Next Event:
Eventname hour:minut
```

for ex if we are in day 14 at hour * and min 32 to show the event that`s coming next (in this case event2)

if we are in day 14 at hour 14 and min 6 to show event3
if we are in day 21 at hour * and min 3 to show test5

and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) Edit your question and include the table (as text) in the question.  (2) Explain what `*` really means.  I sort of understand the data but don't really get what you want to do.

Comment: remade it hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT id, name, 
  CASE WHEN day = '*' THEN DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) ELSE day END day,
  CASE WHEN hour = '*' THEN HOUR(NOW()) ELSE hour END hour,
  CASE WHEN `min` = '*' THEN MINUTE(NOW()) ELSE `min` END `min`
  FROM table1 t 
 WHERE (day >= DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) OR day = '*') 
   AND (hour >= HOUR(NOW()) OR hour = '*')
   AND (`min` >= MINUTE(NOW()) OR `min` = '*')
 ORDER BY day = '*', day,
   hour = '*', hour,
   `min` = '*', `min`
 LIMIT 1;
```

Given your test data set and current date time 2016-09-30 02:18:58 the output would be

```
| id |        name | day | hour | min |
|----|-------------|-----|------|-----|
|  1 | Test event1 |  30 |    2 |  30 |
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab9d/10)

Comment: Hi, that did made the trick a bit but when all events finish for ex and is minute 40 will give no result. should give the next hour first event.

Comment: oh and also day will take over minutes if there is a special event on that day and will not order any more by minutes.